# Apache Beam Streaming from Pub/Sub to ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, elasticsearch-rest-client

I'm writing a java streaming pipeline with Apache Beam that reads messages from Google Cloud PubSub and should write them into an ElasticSearch instance. Currently, I'm using the direct runner, but the plan is to deploy the solution on Google Cloud Dataflow.

First of all, I wrote a pipeline that reads from PubSub and writes to text files and it works. Then, I sat up the ElasticSearch instance and also this works. I wrote some documents with curl and it was easy.

Then, when I tried to perform the write with Beam's ElasticSearch connector, I started to get some error. Actually, I get `ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest`, in spite of the fact that I added the dependency on my pom.xml file.

What I'm doing is essentially this:

```java
messages.apply(
                        "TwoMinWindow",
                        Window.into(FixedWindows.of(new Duration(120*1000)))
                ).apply(
                        "ElasticWrite",
            ElasticsearchIO.write()
            .withConnectionConfiguration(
                             ElasticsearchIO.ConnectionConfiguration
                             .create(new String[]{"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200"}, "streaming_data", "string")
                             .withUsername("xxxx")
                             .withPassword("xxxxxxxx")
                             )
                );
```

Using the DirectRunner, I'm able to connect to PubSub, but I get an exception when the pipeline tries to connect with the ElasticSearch instance:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Lorg/apache/http/Header;)Lorg/elasticsearch/client/Response;
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap (UserCodeException.java:34)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIO$Write$WriteFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeSetup (Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.reflect.DoFnInvokers.tryInvokeSetupFor (DoFnInvokers.java:50)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DoFnLifecycleManager$DeserializingCacheLoader.load (DoFnLifecycleManager.java:104)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DoFnLifecycleManager$DeserializingCacheLoader.load (DoFnLifecycleManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture (LocalCache.java:3528)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync (LocalCache.java:2277)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad (LocalCache.java:2154)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get (LocalCache.java:2044)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get (LocalCache.java:3952)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad (LocalCache.java:3974)
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get (LocalCache.java:4958)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DoFnLifecycleManager.get (DoFnLifecycleManager.java:61)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ParDoEvaluatorFactory.createEvaluator (ParDoEvaluatorFactory.java:129)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ParDoEvaluatorFactory.forApplication (ParDoEvaluatorFactory.java:79)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformEvaluatorRegistry.forApplication (TransformEvaluatorRegistry.java:169)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.run (DirectTransformExecutor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Lorg/apache/http/Header;)Lorg/elasticsearch/client/Response;
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIO.getBackendVersion (ElasticsearchIO.java:1348)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIO$Write$WriteFn.setup (ElasticsearchIO.java:1200)
```

What I added in the pom.xml is :

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
    <version>${beam.version}</version>
  </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-client -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
    <version>${elastic.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

I'm stuck with this problem and I don't know how to solve it. If I use a JestClient, I'm able to connect to ElasticSearch without any issue.

Have you any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a newer version of `RestClient` that does not have the method `performRequest(String, Header)`. If you look at [the latest source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/rest/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestClient.java), you can see that the method takes a `Request` now, whereas in older versions [there were methods that took Strings and Headers](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/b8f4c92d41411e17ec45f3c83dc81d1f12d39751/client/rest/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestClient.java).
These methods were deprecated and then [removed from the code on September 1, 2018](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/f28cddf9518fb83dd9db2ed88a3362dac6c8aeb3#diff-d5bb3520f960a753d8f8a3a2686dfd6b).

Either change your code to use the newer Elastic Search library, or specify an older version of the library (it needs to be before `7.0.x`, e.g. [`6.8.4`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-client/6.8.4)) that is compatible with your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I realized that I was trying to write on ElasticSearch 7.4.2, while the Apache Beam connector supports up to version 6.x.